# Using set list with pgfplotstable

Tags: macros, pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I am trying to create a new column in a table using the set list option, but it will not expand the list when stored in a macro.  I've tried \expandafter in various locations with no joy so far.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}

\noindent This works.
\pgfplotstableset{create on use/first/.style={create col/set list={a,b,c,d,e,f}}}
\pgfplotstablenew[columns={first}]{6}\mytable
\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type]\mytable

\noindent This also works.
\pgfplotstablecreatecol[set list={a,b,c,d,e,f}]{second}\mytable
\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type]\mytable

\noindent This doesn't.
\edef\names{a,b,c,d,e,f}
\pgfplotstablecreatecol[set list={\names}]{third}\mytable
\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type]\mytable
\end{document}
```

[image: tables]

---

Based on Matthew Leingang's answer I figured out how to handle an environment as well.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}

\edef\names{A,B,C,D}
\edef\parms{symbolic x coords={\names},xtick=data}
\def\environ{\begin{axis}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\expandafter\environ\expandafter[\parms]
\addplot coordinates {(A,0) (B,1) (C,1) (D,2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out there is a much simpler solution: /.expanded

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}

\def\names{a,b,c,d,e,f}

\pgfplotstableset{create on use/first/.style={create col/set list/.expanded={\names}}}
\pgfplotstablenew[columns={first}]{6}\mytable
\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type]\mytable

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

I am still a trial-and-error programmer when it comes to `\expandafter`.  But one thing to keep in mind is it expands *tokens* which are either characters or control sequences.  So if you want to expand a bunch of tokens at once, out of order, it's easiest to put them in a macro.  In this case you want to expand the entire optional argument `setlist={\names}` at once.  This will do it.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}

This works.
\pgfplotstableset{create on use/first/.style={create col/set list={a,b,c,d,e,f}}}
\pgfplotstablenew[columns={first}]{6}\mytable
\pgfplotstablecreatecol[set list={a,b,c,d,e,f}]{second}\mytable

\def\names{a,b,c,d,e,f}
\edef\myargs{set list={\names}}
\expandafter\pgfplotstablecreatecol\expandafter[\myargs]{third}\mytable
\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type]\mytable
\end{document}
```

The `\edef\myargs{set list={\names}}` makes `\myargs` expand to `set list={a,b,c,d,e,f}`.  The next line has two `\expandafter`s in it.  The first one hops over `\pgfplotstablecreatecol`, only to find another `\expandafter` to hop over the `[`.  So the first expanded token is `\myargs`, inserting the optional argument.  Then the `[` is put back in place, and finally `\pgfplotstablecreatecol` is expanded.  By that time the token list looks like

```
\pgfplotstablecreatecol[set list={a,b,c,d,e,f}]{third}\mytable
```

which is exactly what you want.

[image: sample code output]

Comment: Same should be possible with `set list/.expanded=\names` but unfortunately there is a bug ticket about it in TikZ v3.00 such that the expansion is not taking place.